# Allow Camera in webpage with dalekjs

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, dalekjs

I have got a webpage where people are able to chat together and see each other through a webcam. Now for some reason i cannot set this option in chrome to always allow the camera.
Is there a way to let dalekjs do that work for me? Or any suggestion on how to pre-set this in chrome? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a flag for enabling the camera access, or on the other hand, disabling the dialog that asks for permission; but if there is one, you can apply it using your Dalekfile like described in this pull request: https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-browser-chrome/pull/8